# All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification after adding stripe

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I created an empty project, just put stripe in gradle,

Gradle line

```
implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:6.1.2'
```

and I'm getting error on this line after syncing here.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
```

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 28.0.0-alpha3, 27.1.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0-alpha3 and
>   com.android.support:design:27.1.0

Comment: Stripe library not used your compile library version use jar file of stripe library  and remove from the gradle. otherwise use stripe library compiled version in your project.

Comment: compiled version you mean jar file?

Comment: What's your compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion ?

Comment: Use resolutionStrategy  to force all support libraries to use same version like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51415063/3624647

Answer (score 2):

Stripe library uses `27.1.0` version of **Android support libraries**. See [Here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/blob/master/build.gradle#L44)

You need to **match** that version with your all android support libraries. or you will get that error

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0-alpha3, 27.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0-alpha3 and com.android.support:design:27.1.0

You can maintain that manually or add following script to **project level build.gradle**

This will force all versions of **Android Support library** to use ***same version*** So you won't have to maintain it manually

```
allprojects {

    // Force all of the primary support libraries to use the same version.
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            eachDependency { details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
                    details.useVersion versions.supportLibrary
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit 1**

Here how you can manage it with more **reliable** way

**dependencies.gradle**

```
buildscript {

    ext.versions = [
            // Basic
            'supportLibrary'       : '27.1.0',
    ]

    allprojects {

        // Force all of the primary support libraries to use the same version.
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                eachDependency { details ->
                    if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
                        details.useVersion versions.supportLibrary
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

project level **build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    . . .
}

apply from: 'dependencies.gradle'
```

module level **build.gradle**

```
dependencies {

    ...

    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${versions.supportLibrary}"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:${versions.supportLibrary}"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:${versions.supportLibrary}"

    ...
}
```

This is how you can easily manage all **Android Support library** versions

Answer (score 0):

The stripe library use the 27.1.0 version in its dependencies so you should use the same version too. Just change it to this:

`implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'`

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'`