# Android Studio - Gradle compilation failed

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

My compile is failing for some reason, but earlier it was working just fine.

This is the error I'm getting when trying to compile the project:

```
Program type already present: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$Behavior
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$Behavior, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

**(Build) app.iml :**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "appjoe.wordpress.com.testdemo"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

    // picasso and volley
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'eu.the4thfloor.volley:com.android.volley:2015.05.28'

    // retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'

    // rxjava & rxandroid
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.16'

    // glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'

    // android views
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
}
```

I'm also getting an error for the second dependency in the dependencies area saying:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 27.1.1, 27.1.0, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 and com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.0 less... (Ctrl+1)
>
> There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion).

Comment: change your glide dependency to this--

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'

Comment: Have look on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51415063/6672577

Comment: Change your support libraries version 27.1.1 and also change compile sdk version 27.

Comment: @RohitSuthar thank you, it worked. How can I close this question?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of in the dependency some libraries(other than support libraries) has used supported libraries version different than yours that's why you are getting this error. you have mixed support libraries dependencies version 26 and 27.

So, you need to use a matching support library which is version 27.1.1. Change your build.gradle to something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27 // use version 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "appjoe.wordpress.com.testdemo"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 27 // targeting api version 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

    // picasso and volley
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'eu.the4thfloor.volley:com.android.volley:2015.05.28'

    // retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'

    // rxjava & rxandroid
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.16'

    // glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'

    // android views
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
}
```

**OR**

Upgrade your libraries version to new version. Just hold cursor on each library. Android studio will tell you by Itself that this library has the new version available.